# 'Mp4' videos with some encoding seems not working | video codec

Tags: ios, video, mp4, h.264, codec

Link to video file: https://d267x6x6dh1ejh.cloudfront.net/posts/97e6bee1-a553-4b88-9597-da5d0a51fd6c.mp4

Above is the sample of mp4 video uploaded by our customers, these videos seem to be working fine in macOS and other android devices but not working on iPhones. We are not sure why. We tried to play it in iOS using Files, Safari (using the above link), and other apps like slack, etc but still, it didn’t work.
Since these videos are uploaded by our customers we couldn’t find how these videos are made.

We were searching about this issue for many days now. Any info on this will be a great help.

Comment: I don't have an iPhone to test so you tell me... Does this [other test MP4](https://files.panomoments.com/longGOP60fps_dashinit.mp4) work okay on the iPhone? Like your own file it has its H264 video encoded with a Profile of `High @ 4.1` but after that there's differences in Scan Type (yours is "interlaced", my link has "progressive") and also in [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo/Download) program... your codec ID shows as "mp42" but on my link it says ID = "iso6", this ID shouldn't be an issue but we'll see when you confirm if my link plays or not..

Comment: I tried this video, but it stoped a frame 74.